# Aspect ratio is locked at 4:3?

Tags: drivers, resolution, display

I just installed Ubuntu on a fairly new laptop, and everything worked fine at first.  However, after I installed a proprietary driver for the cpu and reset the system, the aspect ratio was automatically changed to 4:3, and it doesn't give me an option to change it back to 16:9.  Is there some additional driver for the gpu I need to download?

```
S880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series] [1002:9712]
              Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fddo]
              Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
              Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu have you installed ? 12.04 or 13.04 ?